# Get Facebook user post/status updates from specific geolocation (long, lat)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my thesis i am analyzing social activity of users in specific location defined by longitude and latitude. I have managed to get desired tweets using tweets API but Facebook API (and instagram also), especially after lately circumstances is very unclear.

My question is: Is it still possible to query users tweets or status updates from geographic locations? (just text and hashtags from locations - i am not interested in any information related to user personals).

If yes then which access token should i use and which endpoint?

Comment: No, that is not at all possible.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Is that related to latest changes to their API?
Do you know maybe if my goal could be reached otherwise? @CBroe

Comment: No, not related; Facebook has never offered a possibility to search for posts by location to normal 3rd-party apps.